# Chrome html5 canvas shadowBlur

Tags: html, google-chrome, canvas, smoothing

The problem is in how Chrome is making the `shadowBlur` in HTML5 canvas.

How it looks in Chrome:

[image]

How it looks in Opera:

[image]

I need it to look like in Opera, I mean the "smoothing" around it. Or, if there is no way to do this, maybe there is way to make text look smooth in canvas.